# Expression evaluated client side or server side?

Tags: html, thymeleaf, spring-el

I have the following Thymeleaf code snippet:

```
<select name="expiryYear">
    <option th:each="seq : ${#numbers.sequence(0,12)}"
            th:value="${ (new org.joda.time.DateTime()).getYear() + seq}"
            th:text="${ (new org.joda.time.DateTime()).getYear() + seq}"
            th:field="*{expiryYear}"></option>
</select>
```

What I need to know is the `new org.joda.time.DateTime()` will create object on server side or client side?
I need it to be on the server side so that the fields on the form are not affected by client settings.

Answer (score 1):

DateTime is the standard implementation of an unmodifiable datetime class. It is Java implementation not javascript so it must be on the server-side.